# ation stored in github.com in my keychain. The authenticity of verifgitcredentials osxkeychain cannot be verified

Tags: git, ssh

I originally created a new repo on Github and cloned it to my local using https but apparently they will only do authentication through SSH or GPG key. The issue is it's continuing to give me the error message when I git push to my repo even though I already added my SSH key to github. I've rebooted my Mac and still asking me for my key.. I'm on Mac Big Sur version 11.6.5 not sure if that's too out of date. Any help is appreciated[image]

Comment: What does `git remote -v` say? And notice that even if you cloned initially with a https url, you can at any time add/remove/change remote endpoints at will, these are not set in stone. If you change the origin url from https to ssh that does not affect anything with the content when you talk to the same backend, they are just different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a git credential message, it means the remote URL is an HTTPS one. SSH is not involved.

For GitHub, the "login" keychain password is your [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: I tried it and didn't work.. I've done everything to try to fix this (added myself as ssh agent since I was getting this response: $ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities. then I did: Identity added: /Users/reidwilliamson/.ssh/id_rsa (reidwilliamson@Reids-MacBook-Pro.local), So I spun up the ssh key and added it to my github account, I also generated a GPG key added that to my github account, then just now added a fine-grained personal access token but still getting the same error when I try to push to my repo..

Comment: @ReidWilliamson SSH agent? But ig the URL is HTTPS, no SSH "item" would be involved, no?